# Is this representation isomorphic to the group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let's consider s representation $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ such that there is a bijection between every linear operator of the image of $\rho$ and the elements of $G$. Is the image of $\rho$  isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: what is a bijection between a linear operator and a group?

Comment: Are there any assumptions on the vectorspace $V$? Is it over a finite field? Or can $G$ be an infinite group?

Comment: at every different group element it correspond a different linear operator

Comment: @SimoBartz Ah, so I gather you are just asking that $\rho$ is injective, and not that there is a bijection $f:GL(V)\to G$ ?

Comment: sorry I expressed my self bad. I edit the post, now it's clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider the representation $\rho:GL(n,\Bbb C)\times \Bbb C^*\to GL(n,\Bbb C)$ sending $(A,z)\mapsto zI_n$. $GL(n,\Bbb C)\times\Bbb C^*$ and the image of $\rho$ have the cardinality of $\Bbb C$, but the former is not abelian when $n>1$.